# Which statistical method can I use to see if there is a correlation between data sets with different size?

Tags: correlation, covariance, ancova, coefficient-of-variation, mancova

For my thesis I want to compare the 3 different test results.
If the results are more than 5, samples are failed.
And I want to show if these tests are similar behaviour (if there is a correlation between)
My problem is the test numbers are not same:
first one is applied 5 times for one sample and the other two tests applied 7 and 8 times.

So my QUESTION: If the data sets have different length, can i still compare these within each other? And how?

Comment: For correlation to make sense, X should be associated with Y. For example, if X is a vector of length 7 representing daily units of bread sold from Monday to Sunday and Y is vector of length 5 representing daily units of butter sold from Monday to Friday, then you may want to consider matching X and Y by "day". So what are your test results and is there a logical association between them (i.e. why are they of different length -I didn't quite understand this from your description)? You also may want to consider a different measure.

Comment: Lets say I have 20 pcs sample from one product, I applied 3 different test to these. After these test there will be some power loss.
First test applied to 5 pcs
Second test applied to 7 pcs
Third test applied to 8 pcs.

And I want to compare the result of these 3-different test and want to see if there is a correlation between these test results.

That is my case. As I have different number of tests (5,7,8), I have different vector-lengths.